# PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to write a PowerShell cmdlet which accepts multiple inputs for a single parameter.

For example, I could do the following easily:

```
Get-CountryList -Group "a" -Category "x"
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
Get-CountryList -Groups "a b c d" -Category "x"
```

(or)

```
Get-CountryList -Groups "a,b,c,d" -Category "x"
```

I searched, but I could not find how to do this.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a single string as the parameter, but you should be passing an *array* of strings:

```
Get-CountryList -Groups "a" -Category "x"
Get-CountryList -Groups "a","b","c","d" -Category "x"
```

You can configure this inside the function if you want as well:

```
Function Get-CountryList {
   Param (
      [String[]]$Groups,
      [String]$Category
   )
   ...
}
```

Comment: Worked well. Thank you.